# Is it beneficial to buy a new engine for a truck?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I am currently using Valiant F16H and it has 600HP engine. It goes at a maximum speed of 90-95 km/h. I am thinking of upgrading the engine to 750HP. Would it be beneficial?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you probably guessed, you don't get a benefit to your maximum speed, as you'd be speeding if you went any faster than this. (Well, you can go faster, but you really shouldn't.)

But, you do get better *acceleration* and the ability to keep your speed up when going *uphill*. Depending how heavy (or light) loads you have been pulling thus far, you may not have noticed a need for these yet. But once you get to the heavier loads, you'll notice the benefits of upping your acceleration and being able to maintain your speed when driving uphill.